# positioning the camera in LIBGDX

Tags: camera, libgdx, screen

I am working on a game and I want the camera to position in the center ie. the player must be able to see both the Y and Y' ( for example ) and not only either Y or Y'. 
   I need exactly as the below attached image .
[image: expected output screenshot]

In the above image, the player is in the mid of the screen . But in my game, I am getting like the below attached image,

[image: actual output]

As you can see, I am able to position the camera as needed but when I do so,red bars are appearing below the sprite . Is there any way to get rid of this red bar ?

Here is my screen code,

```
   public Playscreen( )
   {
    ....
    this.gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();                                                                                  
    this.gamePort = new StretchViewport(MyJungleGame.V_WIDTH / MyJungleGame.PPM, MyJungleGame.V_HEIGHT / MyJungleGame.PPM, gamecam);
      renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / MyJungleGame.PPM); 
    gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2,                                                                                               
    ....
  }
```

My update method,

```
 public void update(float dt) {      

        int newwidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2;
        int newheight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3;
        gamecam.position.x = this.gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().x + gamePort.getWorldWidth() / newwidth;// wana keep track of mario whn it moves in x axis and dont wana move d cam whn mario moves in y axis
        gamecam.position.y = this.gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().y + gamePort.getWorldHeight() /3.5f;        
            .......
  }
```

I just played with the numbers to get the below result but I don't know how to get rid of these bars. Please help . I am a beginner in libgdx. Thanks in advance

Comment: camera.position.set(xPosition, startHeightOfWorld + camera.height / 2);

Answer (score 0):

The red bars are there because the first thing you do is clear the screen and draw a background color, the latter is by default red.

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f); // <-- makes it red
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

So either you want to change this to a more desirable color or move the camera up higher so the bottom matches the bottom of your world.

```
    gamecam.position.y = this.gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().y + gamePort.getWorldHeight() /3.5f;
```

You are on the right track here but I do not understand the hard-coded `3.5f`. If you would do:

```
gamecam.position.y = this.gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().y + gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2f;
```

Then your character should be located at the bottom of the screen. In the example screenshot you posted the character is located 2 blocks above the bottom edge of the screen so:

```
float cameraPositionY = this.gamehero.heroBody.getPosition().y + gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2f;
cameraPositionY-= tileHeight * 2;
gamecam.position.y = cameraPositionY;
```

This off course pushes the camera down and you need to fill this up with tiles otherwise you will still see that background.

PS:

You do not need `this` everywhere. You only need to use this to access a variable when there is a overload parameter named exactly alike.

```
private int score;
private int highScore;
public void setScore(int score)
{
    this.score = score;
    if (score > highScore)... // <- No need to use "this" for highScore.
}
```

Comment: I hard coded the value 3.5f because that's pushing the camera upwards like I needed. I am getting the result exactly as needed if the value is 4f. Problem is , red bar appears . And if the hard-coded value is 2.5f then. there are no red bars but the result is not like how I needed. So, If I subtract the tile height as you said , will I be getting just like the example pic I showed ? @Menno Gouw

Comment: Seems to me you are trying random numbers then. That won't ever fix your problem. The red bars are just the background and if you are not drawing anything in that place this background shows up. So either place the camera correctly with numbers that have a meaning, like I show in my answer. Or add a row/column of tiles.

Comment: I have tired it but still I am not getting it and the red bars are shown only when the player is on the ground but when the player's y pos is bit above the ground the red bars don't appear and I can see the output as expected like the ex. screen shot shown. Problem lies only when the player's y val is 0. I don't know how to resolve it. I tried subtracting the camera's y pos with the tile height as you said but the value came in negative that's because initially the player's y pos is 0 and when the value is subtracted with the tile pixel height which is 16 then value came around -16 @Menno Gouw

Comment: You want to limit your camera on the y axis then. So check if it's y position is below a certain value then set it to its value. Or put the yPos first in its own variable and use `Math.Clamp`.